# Android compass and camera enable tutorial

Tags: android, camera, compass-geolocation

I wonder if anyone could give me some guides, I am looking for tutorials to creating a simple compass application that points north and then perhaps move on to determining nearby GPS co-ordinates.

I also looking for a tutorail that enable me to switch on the camera (on the android phone) when user click the camera button.

Can anyone suggest me any of good tutorials for me to get start please.

Much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link for compass provided by Android.

[Compass on Android Guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Compass.html)

And, second you want to open the camera of the phone or switch to it then try this.
[Opening Camera Intent in Android](http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/)

You need to open the Camera Intent already exist in Android API. Thanks